# How to set the value of dropdownlist from data table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I'm trying to bind dropdownlist from data table, where data table contain departmentID, and DepartmnentName. binding is successful, but how to set the value of the items?

```
    dt = objDeparment.SelectAll().Tables[0];
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(dr[1].ToString()); //binding the dropdownlist with department names
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't just add the string, add a `ListItem` (which exposes [more useful constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this):

```
DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr[1].ToString(), dr[0].ToString()));
//                                   ^^--Text          ^^--Value
```

(assuming the "value" you want is in `dr[0]`, just use whatever holds the actual value for your code)

You could also bind the control directly to the `DataTable` instead of adding items in a loop.  Something like this:

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = objDeparment.SelectAll().Tables[0];
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "some column";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "another column";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```